# ARM TTK Tests "apiVersions Should Be Recent" failing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, arm, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to implement some tests for the ARM template that I've got in my pipeline but I'm getting a failure on api versions being too old.

```
api versions must be the latest or under 2 years old (730 days) - API
version 2017-07-01 of Microsoft.Logic/workflows is 1822 days old in
template file logicApp.template.json
```

But I can't find a more recent version to pick from in the options that appear in editor.

My template looks like this...

```
........"type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[variables('createIncidentLogicAppName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }......
```

Is there a way around this? If the latest api version available is more than 2 years old I don't see how I can ever make this pass.

Comment: just checked the schema at the top of the file and it is set to 
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
wondering if this is why I can't pick new version of API

Comment: ok I changed my version to "2019-05-01" (ignoring the warning about schema validation) and got past that failing test